# Is there any software to solve this large scale convex optimization problem?

Tags: convex-optimization

I want to solve the following large scale convex problem:

$min\ \ ||A$**u**-**b**$||_2^{2}+
||$**U**$_{(1)}||_*+||$**U**$_{(2)}||_*+||$**U**$_{(3)}||_*$

where **U** is a three order tensor, **U**$_{(i)}$ is a matrix whose column are the mode-$i$ fibers of **U**(i=1,2,3),**u** is vec(**U**).

The software 'cvx' can solve this problem, but it can not deal with the large scale problem, I read some papers but I can't implement them, is there any software to do this?

Comment: I suggest reading the documentation for Yalmip and the solvers that can be used by it here http://users.isy.liu.se/johanl/yalmip/pmwiki.php?n=Solvers.Solvers

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my question above

Comment: Maybe Gurobi? There is a long list there.

Comment: Gurobi certainly cannot, no.